# how to disable and enable button if user enter all required info

Tags: iphone, nsthread

**Given** :
Below is the form that user must enter and the top right is a button which allows user to navigate to another screen.

[image]

**Goal**: the top right button is disabled until the user has input all of the required fields. Once the user has input all required fields, the button will be enabled and user will be allows to press it allowing navigation to next screen

**Question**:how can I achieve this task **using thread in iphone.**

Please help if you have any clues for this

Thanks

PS: I apology for unclear question at the beginning. I have just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIButton inherits from UIControl

Simply use the button.enabled property.

```
button.enabled = false;

// Detect when all inputs are valid

button.enabled = true;
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/state

Comment: yes but I am looking for the way to validate all the fields. It looks like using another technique to manage all required fields. if the condition is satisfied, enable the button automatically

Comment: @ttran - that wasnt really the way you stated the question!  But to answer, you can control all actions going on, when a user taps a field, when they exit, etc... you should be able to validate that the input either arent equal to the default text, or something.  Hold a boolean flag for each one and when all are true, set the button enabled.  Set the boolean true when user input a valid, and check for all trues upon entering of any and all fields.  This will  allow them to enter in any order while still doing what you want!

Comment: thanks for your comments. sorry for unclear question at the beginning.Please see my updated OP

Comment: @ttran - Your question hasnt REALLY changed.  What does threads have to do with the functionality you desire?

Comment: because at the beginning I thought we have 2 processes :1. filling the forms 2.keeping track with filled fields, if all are filled in ----> enalbe button. I am not quite sure that my way is an appropriate approach. Maybe there is another easier way out there

Comment: @ttran - This really isnt a multi-thread problem. You really only have a single thing going on at once.  If the user hasnt entered any new information, then there is no need to continuously checking the state.  The state will really only be able to really change if the user inputs something new, detect it at that time!

Comment: Even with your change to the original question, I think my answer would have done what you wanted. trumpetlicks is correct, this isn't a multi threaded problem.

Answer (score 1):

Quick naive solution:

Set a unique tag for each text field:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*) cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    // Create/Re-use Table Cell code here...

    cell.theTextField.tag = indexPath.row;
}
```

Create boolean flag for each text field.

Implement UITextViewDelegate and set it as the delegate for each text field. You need to create this method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Check whether the user has set valid input and if they did, set the boolean flag to corresponding to that text field to true.

After the validation for each text field, check if all flags are true. If they are, enable the navigation button.

Comment: thanks for your comments. sorry for unclear question at the beginning.Please see my updated OP